# What if there's 1 month discrepancy in my background check for employment?

Tags: resume, job-search, software-development, background-check, developer

Just out of curiosity, I was wondering , if I worked for company X for 5 months and listed on my resume that I worked there for 6 months. Does it create a problem for me ? I currently work for a different company but I don't think they will last long so I don't plan on putting them on my resume. If I list the previous company I worked for (which was a large corporation) with an additional 1 month listed , will it cause any issues? Will I have the chance of losing a potential opportunity during a background check?

Comment: Why do you want to list 6 months in your resume if you have only worked 5 months? Generally, padding your work experience is frowned upon. How seriously the company reacts to such padding depends on the company.

Comment: For being one month off?  They're just going to assume you were confused about the exact dates, or that you and the employer rounded differently.  With such a small discrepancy I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could - when someone stumbles over the discrepancy you´ll have to explain it. An I don´t see how you could do that in a positive way.

You could just leave the one month out of you CV altogether. Having a one-month gap in you CV is nothing to worry about. If your "failed" engagement with your current employer only last´s a few weeks, it is reasonable to keep it out of you CV as you may not have made any relevant experience in that time.
Rather explain the gap with personal projects, though.